# Как реализовать пул асинхронных http запросов на Go

Tags: golang, http

Нужно реализовать такую задачу:
Есть структура, поля которой заполняются resposne объектами с нескольких http запросов. Нужно сделать так, чтобы запросы выполнялись асинхронно(каждый метод в котором выполняется запрос запускать через go), также каждый метод должен записать результат в соответствующее поле структуры, и также если в одном из запросов произойдет ошибка, то метод со всей этой конструкцией должен вернуть ошибку.

Вот пример реализации(синхронной) в коде:

```
type ResponseObject struct {
  Response1 string
  Response2 string
  Response3 string
}

func fn(ctx context.Context, value string) (*ResponseObject, error) {
  resp1, err := getApi1(ctx, value)
  if err != nil {
    return nil, err
  }
  resp2, err := getApi2(ctx, value)
  if err != nil {
    return nil, err
  }
  resp3, err := getApi3(ctx, value)
  if err != nil {
    return nil, err
  }

  return &ResponseObject{
    Response1: resp1,
    Response2: resp2,
    Response3: resp3,
  }, nil
}
```

Как более лаконично реализовать подобный пример только с асинхронным выполнением запросов?

Answer (score 0):

Я бы сделал что-нибудь в таком духе:

```
type Task struct {
    id      string
    ctx     context.Context
    request string
    api     func(context.Context, string) (string, error)
    Result  Result
}

type Result struct {
    Err      error
    Response string
}

func (task *Task) handler(wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    task.Result.Response, task.Result.Err = task.api(task.ctx, task.request)
    if wg != nil { wg.Done() }
}
```

Каждая задача имеет уникальный идентификатор (для логирования ошибок, например), параметры, точку для вызова и место для результата. Обработчики запускаются в группе, чтобы запускающий поток мог дождаться завершения всех обработчиков.

Пример использования:

```
func fn(ctx context.Context, value string) ([]Result, error) {
    var taskList []Task = []Task{
        Task{
            id:      "Api1",
            ctx:     ctx,
            request: value,
            api:     getApi1,
        },
        Task{
            id:      "Api2",
            ctx:     ctx,
            request: value,
            api:     getApi2,
        },
        Task{
            id:      "Api3",
            ctx:     ctx,
            request: value,
            api:     getApi3,
        },
    }
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for i := range taskList {
        wg.Add(1)
        go taskList[i].handler(&wg)
    }
    wg.Wait()
    result := []Result{}
    errors := []string{}
    for _, tsk := range taskList {
        result = append(result, tsk.Result)
        if tsk.Result.Err != nil {
            errors = append(errors, fmt.Sprintf("%s: failed: %s", tsk.id, tsk.Result.Err.Error()))
        }
    }
    if len(errors) > 0 {
        return result, fmt.Errorf("%s", strings.Join(errors[:], ";"))
    }
    return result, nil
}
```

После запуска всех обработчиков основной поток ждёт `wg.Wait`, после чего обрабатывает - собирает результаты и формирует одну большую ошибку на всех.

**UPD**

Вариант с одной ошибкой на всех. В этом примере контекст снабжается функций отмены `WithCancel`, чтобы та горутина, в которой приключилась ошибка, смогла остановить все остальные.

В общем случае прерывание контекста в сетевой функции вернёт ошибку, которая будет возвращена вверх по стеку, поэтому в обрабочике таска используется глобальный контейнер для ошибки, который сохраняет только самую первую. Объект типа `sync.Once` реализует паттерн синглетон, функция в методе `Do` этого объекта вызывается ровно один раз за время существования объекта.

```
type GlobalError struct {
    err    error
    setter sync.Once
}

func (ge *GlobalError) HasError() bool {
    return ge.err != nil
}

func (ge *GlobalError) SetError(err error) {
    ge.setter.Do(func() { ge.err = err })
}

func (ge *GlobalError) Unwrap() error {
    return ge.err
}

func (ge *GlobalError) Error() string {
    return ge.Error()
}

type Task struct {
    id      string
    ctx     context.Context
    cancel  context.CancelFunc
    request string
    api     func(context.Context, string) (string, error)
    Err     *GlobalError
    Result  string
}

func (task *Task) handler(wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    var err error
    task.Result, err = task.api(task.ctx, task.request)
    if !task.Err.HasError() {
        task.Err.SetError(fmt.Errorf("task '%s' failed: %w:", task.id, err))
        task.cancel()
    }
    if wg != nil {
        wg.Done()
    }
}

func fn(ctx context.Context, value string) ([]string, error) {
    ge := &GlobalError{}
    var cancel context.CancelFunc

    ctx, cancel = context.WithCancel(ctx)
    var taskList []Task = []Task{
        Task{
            id:     "Api1",
            ctx:    ctx,
            cancel: cancel,
            Err:    ge,

            request: value,
            api:     getApi1,
        },
        Task{
            id:     "Api2",
            ctx:    ctx,
            cancel: cancel,
            Err:    ge,

            request: value,
            api:     getApi2,
        },
        Task{
            id:     "Api3",
            ctx:    ctx,
            cancel: cancel,
            Err:    ge,

            request: value,
            api:     getApi3,
        },
    }
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for i := range taskList {
        wg.Add(1)
        go taskList[i].handler(&wg)
    }
    wg.Wait()
    if ge.HasError() {
        return nil, ge.Unwrap()
    }
    result := []string{}

    for _, tsk := range taskList {
        result = append(result, tsk.Result)
    }
    return result, nil
}
```

Comment: Хотелось при возникновении первой ошибки отменять все операции которые ещё не выполнились, и возвращать её. И исключить API метод, который используется для всех запросов, для того чтобы для каждого запроса был свой метод.

Comment: @СергейМельниченко про каждый метод я не понял, взял ваши методы `getApi1` и ко и вложил их в таски. Добавил завершение по ошибке и возврат первой случившейся ошибки.

Answer (score 0):

В вашем случае вы можете использовать стандартную `errgroup.WithContext`

```go
func fn(ctx context.Context, value string) (*ResponseObject, error) {

    result := &ResponseObject{}

    eg, ctx := errgroup.WithContext(ctx)

    eg.Go(
        func() error {
            resp1, err := getApi1(ctx, value)
            if err != nil {
                return nil, err
            }
            result.Response1 = resp1
            return nil
        },
    )

    eg.Go(
        func() error {
            resp2, err := getApi2(ctx, value)
            if err != nil {
                return nil, err
            }
            result.Response2 = resp2
            return nil
        },
    )

    eg.Go(
        func() error {
            resp3, err := getApi3(ctx, value)
            if err != nil {
                return nil, err
            }
            result.Response3 = resp3
            return nil
        },
    )

    return result, eg.Wait()
}
```